# ergodic measures of rational rotation

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, rotations, ergodic-theory

Let $R: [0,1]\to[0,1]$, with $ R(x)=x+\alpha \mod 1 $ and $ \alpha = \frac{p}{q} $ a rational rotation map on the unit interval. I want to proof the following assertion

> the ergodic measures for $R$ are of the form $ \mu =\sum\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{\delta_{\{x_i\}}}{q} $ for some $x_1,\dots,x_n\in[0,1]$ (and where $\delta_{\{x_i\}}$ denotes the dirac measure).

My understanding is, that to be $R$- ergodic, the measure $\mu$ has to be atomic and concentrated on a finite number of atoms, which - I'm guessing - are going to be the the measures that are concentrated on the finite orbits of points. My proof so far:

Let $ A $ be a $ R $-invariant set, i.e. $ R^{-1}A=A $. I can assume, that $ A $ is not empty (the empty set is a trivial case). So there exists a point $ x\in A $. Since $ \alpha $ is rational, it's clear, that the orbit of $ x $ is a finite set $ orb(x)=\{x_1,\dots,x_q\} $. Since $ R^{-1}A=A $ and clearly the points of the orbit map onto each other, it follows that $ \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subset A $. Since $ R $ is ergodic, $ \mu(A)\in\{0,1\} $. First, we assume, that $ \mu(A) = 1 $. It's easy to see, that the $ R $-Orbits of points in $ [0,1] $ are $ R $-invariant sets, this means, that $ \mu(\{x_1,\dots,x_q\})\in \{0,1\} $.

If $ \mu(\{x_1,\dots,x_q\}) = 1 $, then $ \mu = \sum\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{\delta_{\{x_i\}}}{q} $.

If $ \mu(\{x_1,\dots,x_q\})= 0 $, then $ \mu(A\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_q\}) =1 $. This means there is another $ \hat{x}\in A\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_q\} $. And since $ A\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_q\} $ is still $ R $-invariant, the whole finite orbit of $ \hat{x} $ is a subset of $ A\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_q\} $:  $ orb(\hat{x})=\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_q\}\subset A\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_q\}. $

Now we can proceed the same way as before:

$ \{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_q\} $ is a $ R $-invariant set, this means $ \mu(\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_q\})\in\{0,1\} $. If $ \mu(\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_q\})=1 $, then $ \mu= \sum\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{\delta_{\{\hat{x_i}\}}}{q} $. If $ \mu(\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_q\})=0 $, we look again at $ A\setminus(\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\cup\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_q\}) $ and repeat the same procedure on this set.

So my questions are

- is the proof correct so far? In particular: is it valid, that $ \mu(\{x_1,\dots,x_q\}) = 1 $ implies $ \mu = \sum\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{\delta_{\{x_i\}}}{q} $ ?
- how can I handle the case $ \mu(A) = 0 $? (Then $ \mu(\{x_1,\dots,x_q\})= 0 $ as well, so I guess $ \mu $ has to be concentrated on some other orbit, but I don't know how to formalize that part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\mu(\{x_1,\dots,x_q\}) = 1$ implies $\mu = \sum\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{\delta_{\{x_i\}}}{q}$ is correct. But I do not understant how this close the case $\mu (A)=1$ since you can repeat infinitely times your procedure without reaching a atom of the measure.
- If $A$ is invariant and $\mu(A)=0$ then $A^c$ the complement, is also invariant and $\mu(A^c)=1$. That might help.
- I think a working strategy is to do a dichotomy. Take a invariant ergodic measure $\mu$. If $A\subset[0,1/q[$ we will call $\hat{A}=\cup_{i=0}^{q-1}R^i(A)$. $\hat{A}$ is always invariant for $R$.

Let's called $A^0=[0,1/q[$. We have $\mu(A^0)=1/q$ (because of invariance and $\hat{A^0}$ is $[0,1]$ .

Now you can cut $A^0$ in two parts $A^1_1=[0,1/2q[$ and $A^1_2=[1/2q,1/q[$, $\hat{A^1_1}$ and  $\hat{A^1_2}$ are a partition of $[0,1]$ and are disjoint, by ergodicity there is $i_1 \in \{0,1 \}$ such that  $\mu(\hat{A^1_{i_1}})=1$.

Doing this again and again you will find a sequence of set $A^k \subset [0,1/q[$ with the following properties :

- $A^{k+1} \subset A^K$
- $diam(A^k)=\frac{1}{q*2^k}$
- $\mu(\hat{A^k})=1$

Taking the intersection of all this set you find just a point $x$, and then $\mu=\sum\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{\delta_{\{x_i\}}}{q}$.

Comment: but if i find one set $A$ such that $\nu(A)>0$ and $\mu_x(A)>0$, why does this imply that $\mu_x$ and $\nu$ are not singular? I get that this holds, if $\nu$ has no point masses, but why can i assume that?

Comment: To be singular mean that if for a measurable set $A$, $\mu(A) > 0$ then $\nu(A) =0$, this is the definition.

Comment: I do not understand your second question. You do not need any hypothesis id $\nu$ has a point masse or not.

Comment: I've never heard this definition of singular measures. The definition I know is: Two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular, iff there is a measurable set $E$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ and $\nu(E)=1$. This is not equivalent to the definition you stated. For example Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on [0,1] is singular to $\delta_{\{1/2\}}$, but both measures give weight to the set $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]$

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer to give an other proof.